# How to enable website to zoom and view in small devices

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, bootstrap-4, meta

I done website in bootstrap and still is not responsive in small devices and i seen many websites are responsive without using bootstrap or maybe media query.
Those responsive websites look like this :

[image: Should look like]

**code**

[image]

But mine look like this [image: My website]

**code**

[image]

I dont know how to make my site to zoom and view like first one. Am struck please help..Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used 
Grid Classes
The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)
The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.
Please check

Answer (score 0):

Based on size of screen they have some attributes such as

col-xs-$    Extra Small Phones Less than 768px
col-sm-$    Small Devices   Tablets 768px and Up
col-md-$    Medium Devices  Desktops 992px and Up
col-lg-$    Large Devices   Large Desktops 1200px and Up